# Large ping times in normal mode, okay ping times in safe mode

Tags: macos, wifi, macbook-pro, ping

I pinged google.com to see that ping times ranged from 54 ms to over 2000 ms on my MBA. After a quick isolation and testing, I figured that it was my MBA only issue. I log into safe mode on my MBA with Mountain Lion and I suddenly get ping times of around 15 to 30 ms, which I think are normal from my place and thus okay.

Now that I know ping times are okay in safe mode, how do I hunt down, what might be the issue with my MBA in normal mode? Any clear procedure you advise?

Comment: What DNS server are you using? Do you have any networking extensions installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue affected several people after upgrading to Mountain Lion. For many, reducing their MTU size solved the issue:

1. Open **System Preferences**.
2. Select **Network**.
3. Select your connection and choose **Advanced...**
4. Select **Hardware**.
5. Change **Configuration** to **Manually**
6. Reduce the MTU size to 1300. Most people had good experiences with this value.
7. Observe how `ping` behaves over time. You can further reduce the MTU size in steps of 4.

However, there seems to be another issue: Proxies. The solution suggested here is:

1. Open **System Preferences**.
2. Select **Network**.
3. Select your connection and choose **Advanced...**
4. Select **Proxies**.
5. Turn off **Auto Discovery Proxies**.
6. **Apply** the settings.

But this should be fixed with an upgrade to OS X 10.8.1 (not sure if an upgrade to Mountain Lion directly brings you to the latest upgrade, or to 10.8.0).

Actually, I would first try the upgrade to 10.8.1. If this does not work, try the proxy solution. If this does not work, try the MTU size reduction.